# Problem accessing an array from within a function

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nodemailer

I am creating a app that will scrape Indeed and then will send me an email of the array. I have scrapped the postings successfully and can send emails; but when I try to send the email all that I get is [object, Object] in my email.

```
const PORT =8000;
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express()
const url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Junior+engineer&l=Remote&fromage=1';

//Axios will return a promise and once the promise is returned we will get the response(data)//

axios(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const indeedJobPostings =[]

        //After cheerio has loaded our html, we begin by searching through a .resultContent class for our needed title and company //
        $('.resultContent',html).each(function(){
             title = $(this).find('.jobTitle').text()
             company = $(this).find('.companyName').text()
            indeedJobPostings.push({
                title, company
            })
            
        })
        ////////////
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 587,
            secure: false,
            requireTLS: true,
            auth: {
                user: 'username',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });

        let mailOptions = {
            from: 'email',
            to: 'email',
            subject: 'Test',
            html: `<h2>Here are your daily job postings from Indeed:</h2> <ul>${indeedJobPostings}</ul>`
        };

        console.log('post log',indeedJobPostings, mailOptions)

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error.message);
            }
            console.log('success');
        });

        ///////////
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

When I console.log(indeedJobPosting, mailOptions) indeedJobPostings prints as suspected but mailOptions sends this:

```
{
  from: 'email',
  to: 'email',
  subject: 'Test',
  html: '<h2>Here are your daily job postings from Indeed:</h2> <ul>[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]</ul>'
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` will dump a variable regardless of type. I think your `mailOptions.html ` is likely looking for a string, especially considering your are using string templates.

Comment: The emails I am getting are the will show the exact same as whats in the mailOptions html. Ill just get an email that states [object, Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indeedJobPostings.push({
    title, company
})
```

populates the `indeedJobPostings` array with objects which have `title` and `company` properties.  Converting this to a string in the template expression

```
${indeedJobPostings}
```

create a comma separated list of "[object Object]" strings which result from `Object.prototype.toString` converting the objects to strings, which are then  listed by `Array.prototype.toString` using comma separators in its own `toString` operation.

You could either explicitly convert `indeedJobPostings` object entries to text when creating the email body, or perhaps push text in the first place:

```
indeedJobPostings.push(`Title: ${title}\nCompany: ${company}\n\n`);
```

(for example).

Comment: Thank you I struggled nearly all day!